# Symfony FOSRest bundle Installation error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I am going to use Symfony Framework 3.3 for API development.

I am following these steps written in this blog:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/rest-api-in-symfony-3-1/

In the first minutes of installment I faced off with a problem.

> An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'"
>   command:
>   Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException:
>   Unrecognized option "fos_rest" under "swiftmailer.mailers.default" in
>   ~/Sites/selfdev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/ArrayNode.
>   php:317

where I have just copy-pasted this into my config.yml file

```
  # FOSRest Configuration
    fos_rest:
        body_listener: true
        format_listener:
            rules:
                - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
        param_fetcher_listener: true
        view:
            view_response_listener: 'force'
            formats:
                json: true
```

what shall I do to get over this error?

Comment: Maybe you pasted config incorrectly?

Comment: Could you show us your composer.json and config.yml files?

Comment: @BDS guys problem was just indentation